# How can I encapsulate data in ethereum transactions?

Tags: transactions, contract-design

How can data be encapsulated in an Ethereum transaction so that the block chain can record state of external system? Am I limited to using JavaScript type protocols?

Are tools provided for storing this sort of data?

Answer (score 3):

You can put any arbitrary hexadecimal data in a transaction, in geth or web3.js just use

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: recipientAddress, data: "0xabcd1234", gas: 100000})
```

You'll need to increase the gas as you increae the amount of data.

Comment: Thanks,  I found I can maybe do this in serpent https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Serpent